# ORM for mysql now() - Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following sql

```
select * from bids where deleted_at is  null 
and  publication_date <= now() and open_date >= now()
```

I want to write it using ORM

```
   $bids = Bid::where('publication_date','<=','now()')->where('open_date','>=','now()')->get();
```

It is not working , then i rewrite is as below

```
$bids=DB::select(DB::raw('select * from bids where deleted_at is  null and  publication_date <= now() and open_date >= now()'));
```

How to write above query on ORM,
I think `now()` is giving problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`whereRaw` method](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent):

`$bids = Bid::whereRaw('publication_date <= now() and open_date >= now()')->get();`

Comment: You can also just use DB::raw("NOW()") within a where statement if you don't want to completely go raw with an entire query.